# Creating GDI+ bitmaps in memory and then saving as png

Tags: c++, codeblocks, gdi+

I am new to C++ and been having trouble with writing a function using the GDI+ library to create a new bitmap in memory ( so not opening/reading an existing bitmap); then drawing on the bitmap; before saving it to png. In particular, I am having problems with the bitmap creation and saving code. I am constrained to using codeblocks and I can't use visual studios, even if I wanted to.  The code is as follows:

```
#include "drawImage.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <objidl.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace Gdiplus;

drawImage::drawImage(){}

void drawImage::DrawBitmap(int width, int height){
  GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
  ULONG_PTR           gdiplusToken;
  GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

  {
    //Create a bitmap
    Bitmap myBitmap(width, height, PixelFormatCanonical);
    Graphics g(&myBitmap);
    Pen blackpen(Color(255,0,0,0), 3);

    //draw on bitmap
    int x1 = 1;
    int x2 = 200;
    int y1 = 1;
    int y2 = 200;
    g.DrawLine(&blackpen, x1,y1,x2,y2);

    // Save bitmap (as a png)
    CLSID pngClsid;
    GetEncoderClsid(L"image/png", &pngClsid);
    myBitmap.Save(L"C:\\test\\test.png", &pngClsid, NULL);
  }

  GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
}
```

The issues I am having are as follows:

1. The 'saving' code does not compile and gives the error message "'GetEncoderClsid' was not declared in this scope". However, I got this direct from the Microsoft website [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533837(v=vs.85).aspx). I don't think this is the proper way of converting to png but I dont know an alternative way?
2. When the code is compiled and run (by commenting out the saving code), it then crashes on the line "Bitmap *myBitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormatCanonical);" and gives an error message saying my executable has stopped working.

I have added the 'gdi32' linker library and also '-lgdiplus' as a linker option. Also, I have used [this website](http://www.functionx.com/win32/) to help with the gdi stuff although the section on bitmaps only deals with loading existing bitmaps (not creating new ones in memory)

I am totally lost on what to do, so any help or advice on this matter is much appreciated.

Comment: How is `drawImage` defined? How do you call (with what arguments) `DrawBitmap`?

Comment: Off-topic: You are allocating a new object with `new` but you never `delete` it when it is no longer needed. That is bad and results in memory leak as soon as you leave `DrawBitmap`.

Comment: Thanks for the delete advice. I come from programming languages that use garbage collectors. so I am still learing how to do this type of memory management (so I will now delete it at the end of the function). As for your drawImage query, this code is very much exemplar code in order to keep it specific to the problem but I created a class in codeblocks and this is the .cpp code. the main library calls it by the following: drawImage di; di.DrawBitmap(250, 250); (with #include "drawImage.h" as an include statement)

Comment: The same goes for `g` by the way. Per documentation it must be deleted with `delete g`.

Comment: Have you called `GdiplusStartup`?

Comment: no. I havent called gdiplusStartup. How do I do that and why do I need to call it? (apart from the obvious...it startsup gdi+. I added the following delete statements: delete myBitmap;delete g;delete &blackpen;

Comment: `delete &blackpen` is totally wrong and undefined behavior. You only delete if you created an object with `new` or if a library you use is calling for it. blackpen was statically declared and will be freed automatically as soon as its scope is left.

Comment: The GDI+ documentation says that a call to `GdiplusStartup` is required before calling any other library function and a `GdiplusShutdown` at the end of the program. See the first example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534077(v=vs.85).aspx It is not uncommon that libraries require such setup calls, probably to initialize some global variables / check the system they are run on etc.

Comment: I have updated the code as you suggest (and above) but it still crashes.

Comment: `Bitmap *myBitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormatCanonical);` is unusual. Why not take advantage of the automatic garbage collection built into C++, i.e. `Bitmap myBitmap(width, height, PixelFormatCanonical);`?

Comment: I forgot to mention what @IInspectable said, too. The same is true for `Graphics`. It has a constructor from `Image*`. So `Graphics g(&myBitmap)` is totally fine, too, and makes `delete g` obsolete.

Comment: You are also deleting in the wrong order now. First delete `g`, then `myBitmap` and then shutdown. `GdiShutdown` requires all objects to be deleted (see doc) and `g` depends on `myBitmap`.

Comment: @Eichhörnchen: Calling `GdiplusStartup` multiple times is safe, so long as each call is paired with a call to `GdiplusShutdown`. In this specific case, where the application only ever uses GDI+ to render to a bitmap and save it, it's a good idea even to have the startup and shutdown code in the function where GDI+ is used (which unfortunately precludes using GDI+ objects with automatic storage duration).

Comment: the code now runs but it doesnt create a png file at the end?

Comment: [Image::Save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535407.aspx) has a return value.

Comment: `L"C:\test.png"` is wrong. It should be `L"C:\\test.png"`. Also you don't have write access to C: drive. Create directory "c:\test", and then write to `L"C:\\test\\test.png"`

Comment: still does not work Barmak? So what do I do with the reaturn value?

Comment: I get an 'InvalidParameter' status response from the Image::Save function call? Im guessing this is saying I cant save a bitmap as a png. If so then how do I go about saving it to a file?

Comment: I don't know what is `PixelFormatCanonical`. Just remove that or use the values from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms536313(v=vs.85).aspx). For example `Bitmap myBitmap(width, height);`

Comment: Thanks Barmak, that did the trick and its now working. Also, just wondering who marked me down for this question? A bit harsh and unfair I think. I asked a question on something I was struggling with.

Comment: I rolled back the final edit, which removes all traces of the error. That wouldn't be very helpful to future visitors. Marking an answer as accepted is a visual cue for future visitors to easily find the answer that solved the issue. The one you marked as accepted doesn't, though.

Comment: Makes sense about rolling back and I have now selected your answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The core issue is passing the wrong pixel format to the [Bitmap constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536313.aspx). `PixelFormatCanonical` is not one of the supported [pixel formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534412.aspx). It's a bit mask used to determine whether a pixel format is canonical (see [IsCanonicalPixelFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534084.aspx)). You'll have to use a real pixel format, like the default `PixelFormat32bppARGB`.

The following code produces the desired output:

First up, a small helper class for GDI+ initialization. This ensures, that the d'tor (i.e. the call to `GdiplusShutdown`) is executed after all other objects have been destroyed. With respect to order of destruction, it serves the same purpose as the additional scope in the OP. In addition, it also allows for exceptions to be thrown.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;
#include <stdexcept>
using std::runtime_error;

struct GdiplusInit {
    GdiplusInit() {
        GdiplusStartupInput inp;
        GdiplusStartupOutput outp;
        if ( Ok != GdiplusStartup( &token_, &inp, &outp ) )
            throw runtime_error( "GdiplusStartup" );
    }
    ~GdiplusInit() {
        GdiplusShutdown( token_ );
    }
private:
    ULONG_PTR token_;
};
```

This code was taken from the MSDN sample [Retrieving the Class Identifier for an Encoder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533843.aspx).

```
int GetEncoderClsid( const WCHAR* format, CLSID* pClsid )
{
    UINT  num = 0;          // number of image encoders
    UINT  size = 0;         // size of the image encoder array in bytes

    ImageCodecInfo* pImageCodecInfo = NULL;

    GetImageEncodersSize( &num, &size );
    if ( size == 0 )
        return -1;  // Failure

    pImageCodecInfo = (ImageCodecInfo*)( malloc( size ) );
    if ( pImageCodecInfo == NULL )
        return -1;  // Failure

    GetImageEncoders( num, size, pImageCodecInfo );

    for ( UINT j = 0; j < num; ++j )
    {
        if ( wcscmp( pImageCodecInfo[j].MimeType, format ) == 0 )
        {
            *pClsid = pImageCodecInfo[j].Clsid;
            free( pImageCodecInfo );
            return j;  // Success
        }
    }

    free( pImageCodecInfo );
    return -1;  // Failure
}
```

Finally, the GDI+ rendering code. It uses objects with automatic storage duration throughout, making it more compact and safer.

```
void drawImage( int width, int height ) {
    GdiplusInit gdiplusinit;

    //Create a bitmap
    Bitmap myBitmap( width, height, PixelFormat32bppARGB );
    Graphics g( &myBitmap );
    Pen blackpen( Color( 255, 0, 0, 0 ), 3 );

    //draw on bitmap
    g.DrawLine( &blackpen, 1, 1, 200, 200 );

    // Save bitmap (as a png)
    CLSID pngClsid;
    int result = GetEncoderClsid( L"image/png", &pngClsid );
    if ( result == -1 )
        throw runtime_error( "GetEncoderClsid" );
    if ( Ok != myBitmap.Save( L"C:\\test\\test.png", &pngClsid, NULL ) )
        throw runtime_error( "Bitmap::Save" );
}

int main()
{
    drawImage( 200, 200 );
    return 0;
}
```

*Note: It looks like `GetEncoderClsid` shouldn't be required, since those are well-known constants. However, trying to pass the appropriate [WIC CLSID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719882.aspx) (`CLSID_WICPngEncoder`) to `Bitmap::Save` only produced a `FileNotFound` error.*

Answer (score 4):

For 1.: `GetEncoderClsid` is not a library function, it is an example helper defined [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms533843(v=vs.85).aspx). If you want to use it copy the code from the site. (Btw your link explicitly states this.)

For 2.: You need to call `GdiplusStartup` before creating any GDI+ object or calling any GDI+ function. See its documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534077(v=vs.85).aspx).

To be more precise about `GdiplusShutdown` because that seems to be making you new problems: It is required that all GDI+ objects are destroyed before `GdiplusShutdown` is called. That means that objects with static storage (for example `pen`) must go out of scope before `GdiplusShutdown` is called. That is not the case if you call it in `DrawBitmap` in the way you do now. Either call `GdiplusStartup` and `GdiplusShutdown` in `main` or add additional brackets `{}` around your code between `GdiplusStartup` and `GdiplusShutdown`, because these introduce a new scope and `pen` would be destroyed when `}` is reached.

Edit: Nr. 2 was fixed in the question by edit. For the remaining problem and improvement of the code see @IInspectable's answer.

Comment: Many thanks and apologise as I should have been more thorough and caught that. I wont mark this as an answer as it only partially answers the quesiton. Also, I don't know yet (as the code crashes) if this will successfully convert the bitmap to png and then save it. But again thank you and your response is fully appreciated.

Comment: Many thanks to you Eichhornchen and also Ilnspectable. Your help has been invaluable.