# C++ raw HBITMAP to png struct data

Tags: c++, bitmap, png, encode, hbitmap

So I have a `HBITMAP` object that has all of the pixels that I need to send to a server via a socket (Winsock).

The thing is that it needs to be converted to PNG data, so all that needs to be sent is a struct and the server only has to write all that data in to a file.

The only ways I could find were just writing to a file and that's not what I want.
Also I'd rather not use any more libraries, is this possible?

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51383896 for saving `HBITMAP` as png in memory

Comment: There very little difference between writing to a file and writing to a socket. Can't you adapt one of the file writing examples you've found? Or is the real question, how do I change file writing code to socket writing code?